# Lookup row in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, lookup

I have two dataframes (A & B). For each row in A I would like to look up some information that is in B. I tried:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,2]},   index=[4,5])
B = pd.DataFrame({'Y' : [3,4,5]}, index=[4,5,6])

C = pd .DataFrame(A.index)
C .columns = ['I']
C['Y'] = B .loc[C.I, 'Y']
```

I wanted '3, 4' but I got 'NaN', 'NaN'.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `A.join(B)`.

The result is:

```
   X  Y
4  1  3
5  2  4
```

Joining is by index and value from `B` for key `5` is absent, since `A` does
not contain this key.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is make the `index` same , `pandas` is `index` sensitive , which mean they will check the index when do assignment

```
C = pd .DataFrame(A.index,index=A.index) # change here
C .columns = ['I']
C['Y'] = B .loc[C.I, 'Y']
C
Out[770]: 
   I  Y
4  4  3
5  5  4
```

Or just modify your code adding .values at the end

```
C['Y'] = B .loc[C.I, 'Y'].values
```

---

Since you mentioned lookup let us using `lookup`

```
C['Y']=B.lookup(C.I,['Y']*len(C))
#Out[779]: array([3, 4], dtype=int64)
```